# need return value for captured group from last captured string in perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have XML files from which i want to capture init value( tag) for each parameter.I am copying some part of xml for reference.

I have port name and parameter name( tag(MNO) available with me.
eg . port name is XYZ & parameter name is MNO
port name is PQR & parameter name is ABC and GHI

There can be multiple  tag under one  container.

```
                <R-PORT-PROTOTYPE UUID="Oac11eff016c6bb667f357a89xOac11f0ad174240e817fa858f00">
                  <SHORT-NAME>XYZ</SHORT-NAME>
                  <REQUIRED-COM-SPECS>
                    <PARAMETER-REQUIRE-COM-SPEC>
                      <INIT-VALUE>
                        <APPLICATION-VALUE-SPECIFICATION>
                          <SHORT-LABEL>Init_Val</SHORT-LABEL>
                          <CATEGORY>VALUE</CATEGORY>
                          <SW-VALUE-CONT>
                            <SW-VALUES-PHYS>
                              <V>0.071</V>
                            </SW-VALUES-PHYS>
                          </SW-VALUE-CONT>
                        </APPLICATION-VALUE-SPECIFICATION>
                      </INIT-VALUE>
                      <PARAMETER-REF DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE">/SoftwareTypes/Interfaces/MNO</PARAMETER-REF>
                    </PARAMETER-REQUIRE-COM-SPEC>
                  </REQUIRED-COM-SPECS>
                </R-PORT-PROTOTYPE>
                <R-PORT-PROTOTYPE UUID="Oac11eff016c6bb667f357a89xOac11f0ad174240e817f8f55900">
                  <SHORT-NAME>PQR</SHORT-NAME>
                  <REQUIRED-COM-SPECS>
                    <PARAMETER-REQUIRE-COM-SPEC>
                      <INIT-VALUE>
                        <APPLICATION-VALUE-SPECIFICATION>
                          <SHORT-LABEL>Init_0</SHORT-LABEL>
                          <CATEGORY>VALUE</CATEGORY>
                          <SW-VALUE-CONT>
                            <SW-VALUES-PHYS>
                              <V>80</V>
                            </SW-VALUES-PHYS>
                          </SW-VALUE-CONT>
                        </APPLICATION-VALUE-SPECIFICATION>
                      </INIT-VALUE>
                      <PARAMETER-REF DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE">/SoftwareTypes/Interfaces/ABC</PARAMETER-REF>
                    </PARAMETER-REQUIRE-COM-SPEC>
                    <PARAMETER-REQUIRE-COM-SPEC>
                      <INIT-VALUE>
                        <APPLICATION-VALUE-SPECIFICATION>
                          <SHORT-LABEL>Int_ghi</SHORT-LABEL>
                          <CATEGORY>VALUE</CATEGORY>
                          <SW-VALUE-CONT>
                            <SW-VALUES-PHYS>
                              <V>-80</V>
                            </SW-VALUES-PHYS>
                          </SW-VALUE-CONT>
                        </APPLICATION-VALUE-SPECIFICATION>
                      </INIT-VALUE>
                      <PARAMETER-REF DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE">/SoftwareTypes/Interfaces/GHI</PARAMETER-REF>
                    </PARAMETER-REQUIRE-COM-SPEC>
                  </REQUIRED-COM-SPECS>
                </R-PORT-PROTOTYPE>
```

regex :

```
if($test_string=~ /<R-PORT-PROTOTYPE.*?<short-name>Port_name<\/short-name>.*?<V>(.*?)<\/.*?<PARAMETER-REF DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE">.*?Parameter_name<\/PARAMETER-REF>/gis) {
   print $2;
}
```

I need output 80 if parameter is ABC and -80 if parameter is GHI

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse XML, use a DOM parser library.

Comment: The regexp only contains one capture group, so get it with `$1`, not `$2`.

Comment: You have two `PARAMETER-REF` tags and the data ends with `/MNO1` and `/MNO2`. Do you need both `80` and `-80` printed in that case?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Yes....Here there are 2 PARAMETER-REF tag ..but it can be 3 4 or many. Is it possible to read <V> tag in that case?

Comment: @puja I can't see why not. I added an answer.

Comment: @puja I have a little trouble interpreting "_I have port name and parameter name( tag(MNO) available with me. eg . port name is XYZ & parameter name is MNO port name is PQR & parameter name is ABC and GHI_" I must say. What exactly is supposed to be printed for the above XML?

Comment: Expecting output as: Please see my Regex which is giving me wrong output. If port_name is XYZ and Parameter_name is  MNO then Output should be 0.071 . if port_name is PQR and Parameter_name is ABC , expected output is 80 and if port_name is PQR and Parameter_name is GHI , expected output is -80.......FYI...There can be multiple <PARAMETER-REQUIRE-COM-SPEC> under <R-PORT-PROTOTYPE tag so i want to get <V> for each parameter

Comment: @puja when you say `port_name`, you mean `SHORT-NAME`, right?

Comment: Right ...Port name is <SHORT-NAME>XYZ</SHORT-NAME> and Parameter name MNO from string <PARAMETER-REF DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE">/SoftwareTypes/Interfaces/MNO</PARAMETER-REF>

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML).

Here I've combined two `Xpath` queries to find `V` nodes:

- `SHORT-NAME` is `XYZ` and `PARAMETER-REF` (with `DEST` == `PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE`) contains `MNO`.
- `SHORT-NAME` is `PQR` and `PARAMETER-REF` (with `DEST` == `PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE`) contains `ABC` or `GHI`.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'doc.xml');

my $query = q{
    //R-PORT-PROTOTYPE/SHORT-NAME[text()="XYZ"]/..
        //PARAMETER-REF[@DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE"][
            contains(text(),'MNO')
        ]/..//V
    |
    //R-PORT-PROTOTYPE/SHORT-NAME[text()="PQR"]/..
        //PARAMETER-REF[@DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE"][
            contains(text(),'ABC') or contains(text(),'GHI')
        ]/..//V
};

foreach my $vnode ($dom->findnodes($query)) {
    print $vnode->to_literal() . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0.071
80
-80
```

Answer (score 1):

The two ways to get either or both is

1 - Linear   https://regex101.com/r/NYbvI8/1

```
 # https://regex101.com/r/NYbvI8/1
 # if($test_string=~ /<R-PORT-PROTOTYPE.*?<short-name>PQR<\/short-name>(?:.*?<V>(.*?)<\/V>.*?<PARAMETER-REF[ ]DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE">.*?MNO1<\/PARAMETER-REF>)?(?:.*?<V>(.*?)<\/V>.*?<PARAMETER-REF[ ]DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE">.*?MNO2<\/PARAMETER-REF>)?(?(1)|(?(2)|(?!)))/gis)
 
 <R-PORT-PROTOTYPE .*? <short-name>PQR</short-name> 
 (?:
    .*? 
    <V>
    ( .*? )                       # (1)
    </V>
    .*? 
    <PARAMETER-REF [ ] DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE"> .*? MNO1</PARAMETER-REF>
 )?
 (?:
    .*? 
    <V>
    ( .*? )                       # (2)
    </V>
    .*? 
    <PARAMETER-REF [ ] DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE"> .*? MNO2</PARAMETER-REF>
 )?
 
 (?(1)
  | (?(2)
     | (?!)
    )
 )
```

2 - Out of order  https://regex101.com/r/gQJ3cO/1

```
 # https://regex101.com/r/t4M9UB/1
 # if($test_string=~ /<R-PORT-PROTOTYPE.*?<short-name>PQR<\/short-name>(?:(?:(?(1)(?!)).*?<V>(.*?)<\/V>.*?<PARAMETER-REF[ ]DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE">.*?MNO1<\/PARAMETER-REF>)|(?:(?(2)(?!)).*?<V>(.*?)<\/V>.*?<PARAMETER-REF[ ]DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE">.*?MNO2<\/PARAMETER-REF>)){1,2}/gis)
 
 <R-PORT-PROTOTYPE .*? <short-name>PQR</short-name> 
 
 (?:
    (?:
       (?(1) (?!) )
       .*? 
       <V>
       ( .*? )                       # (1)
       </V>
       .*? 
       <PARAMETER-REF [ ] DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE"> .*? MNO1</PARAMETER-REF>
    )
  | 
    (?:
       (?(2) (?!) )
       .*? 
       <V>
       ( .*? )                       # (2)
       </V>
       .*? 
       <PARAMETER-REF [ ] DEST="PARAMETER-DATA-PROTOTYPE"> .*? MNO2</PARAMETER-REF>
    )
 ){1,2}
```